# Select from tablue where value is repeated on same table on another colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
idGoal | idMatch | minute
  1    |    1    |   30
  2    |    1    |   40
  3    |    2    |   30
  4    |    3    |   45
```

I want to get only the goals where the minute are the same on distinct matches.
So it shows idGoal 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
select g.*
from goals g
where exists (select 1
              from goals g2
              where g2.minute = g.minute and
                    g2.idMatch <> g.idMatch
             );
```

In particular, `exists` can take advantage of an index on `(minute, idMatch)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your table:

```
CREATE TABLE goals
(idGoal INT, idMatch INT, minute TINYINT);
```

Your data:

```
INSERT INTO goals
(idGoal, idMatch, minute)
VALUES
(1, 1, 30),
(2, 1, 40),
(3, 2, 30),
(4, 3, 45);
```

Your query:

```
SELECT idGoal
FROM goals
WHERE minute IN
(
  SELECT minute
  FROM goals
  GROUP BY minute
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Your result:

```
idGoal
------
1
3
```